# How can we check programmatically if an Obj-C object no longer exists (has been collected)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nszombie

I have made a Callback class which serves as an object+selector holder for a lightweight reusable delegate model. Here's the code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Callback : NSObject {

    id obj;
    SEL method;
}

@property(nonatomic,assign) id obj;
@property(nonatomic,assign) SEL method;

+(Callback*) new:(id) obj1 :(SEL)method1;

@end
```

And the .m...

```
#import "Callback.h"

@implementation Callback

@synthesize obj;
@synthesize method;

+(Callback*) new:(id) obj1 :(SEL)method1{
    Callback * cb = [[Callback alloc] init];
    cb.obj= obj1;
    cb.method= method1;
    return [cb autorelease];
}

@end
```

The idea is I can just pass in a [Callback new:self :@selector(mymethod:)], or even an NSArray of Callbacks instead of a heavy-weight protocol implementation. Here is an example of it in action:

```
-(void) storeInCache:(NSArray*) contacts{
    if (contacts != nil){
        // TODO
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [self.service request_getContacts:[Callback new:self :@selector(storeInCache:)]];
    // can fire off more requests on the common service class here
    // as long as I give separate Callback method references
}
```

I'm using it to pass through to my HTTP Service class that does a whole bunch of async method requests. Now my service class keeps a weak reference (assign) to the Callback obj it has to call when the async method returns. How can I check at that time whether the 'Callback' obj is now a zombie or not? Is my general approach terrible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't check whether your `Callback` object has been collected. That concept doesn't make sense under garbage collection—the object won't be collected until you have no remaining ways to access the object. You *can* put the `__weak` qualifier on your instance variable, which means that as soon as the object has been collected the variable will become `nil`. So check for the *reference* being nil, not for the object itself having been collected.

If you need a collection of weakly-referenced objects, you need to use `NSPointerArray`, `NSHashTable`, or `NSHashMap`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So in my service class I've declared the property like "@property(nonatomic,assign) Callback * cb;".. where do I put the _weak qualifier?

Comment: `@property(nonatomic,assign) __weak Callback* cb;`

Comment: This is iphone programming.. I've heard that __weak is a garbage collection annotation and therefore is ignored on the iOS platform.. is this true?

Comment: Yes, that's true; I was thrown off by your use of the word "collected," which is really a GC-specific term.

Comment: In a reference-counted environment, you need to handle unhooking your `Callback` object in its `-dealloc` method.